# Context not being injected properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Not to sure why I am getting the following error.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AppManagerDL.AppManagerDBContext' while attempting to activate 'RoundTableWeb.WMS.Controllers.StockController'.

```
public class StockController : ControllerBase {
    // GET: api/<StocksController>
    private readonly AppManagerDBContext _context;
    public StockController(AppManagerDBContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }
```

As you can see I am getting the ApplicaitonDBContext here and setting it to the connetion string.

When I hit my get statement its not registered the di ends up being null.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public object Get(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions) {
       Guid.TryParse("8F553A64-4301-4051-8691-8EBEFF68969D", out Guid result);
       var test = _context.Stockitems.Where(w => w.TennantId == result).ToList();
       return test;
 }
```

The above is here it brakes on the _context.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => 
                 options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();                             
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => 
                  options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
        services.AddRazorPages();
 }
```

But

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configured `ApplicationDbContext` in startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => ...
```

But injected `AppManagerDBContext` in controller:

```
public StockController(AppManagerDBContext context) { ...
```

They have to be same.

Comment: Basically I wanting AppManagerDBContext to be all my crud operations which the user can use as they so wish but the application db context the main database layer i want to keep private how would I do that.

Comment: @rogue39nin: You want to implement something like `Unit of work Pattern`. You should also add it after your dbContext: `services.AddScoped<AppManagerDBContext>();`